# Dynamic type notification is not getting triggered

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, textkit

I'm currently developing in Swift and have run into a problem with the dynamic typing. I have set this code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ExerciseController :UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var exerciseTableView :UITableView

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reload", name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
  }

  func reload() {
    println("reload")
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cellIdentifier = "ExerciseCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
    if !cell {
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.textLabel.text = "Hello"
    cell!.textLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    return cell
  }
}
```

I run my app, and then go to the Settings app to modify the text size, but the notification selector is not getting called and have no idea why. Thanks in advance in resolving this issue, all help is appreciated

*Previously the notification observers where set on viewDidiLoad and deinit but it didn't work either

**UPDATE #1**

I tried the same thing with the keyboard notification and it did work. That would mean that the application is not recognizing when the text size change when it is done

Comment: Shot in the dark, try `@objc(reload) func reload() {`

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. Its appears it is not the selector but that the application is not being notified of the text size action

Comment: I was able to replicate your problem in XCode 6. Then i tried it on an actual unit, and it works correctly, so it must be a bug in XCode, due to be fixed later.

Comment: @AJ_1310 I know it's been a while, but please see update below :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***EDIT 1*** Apple has acknowledged my bug report and merged it with another bug report.

---

I've done a bit of testing, and found that this issue / bug is only prevalent with the iOS 8 simulator, and `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`. Other notifications works as intended, and the `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` is behaving as expected in the iOS 7 simulator. I have submitted a bug-report in radar. Hope this clarifies for people having this issue in the near future.

**EDIT 2**

This now seems to have been fixed. Further more, [this library](https://github.com/bignerdranch/BNRDynamicTypeManager) from Big Nerd Ranch really eases the whole process of setting up dynamic type.